# How to make docker-compose pull new images?

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile

I am using the `latest` tag in my `Dockerfile` in the `FROM` statement:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM registry.website.com/base-image:latest
```

Every time my `latest` version changes I need to re-pull that image.

Unfortunately, docker just takes the cached version.

I tried

`docker-compose build --no-cache`

and
`docker-compose up --build --force-recreate project`

But it always looks like this:

```
> docker-compose up --build --force-recreate project
Building project
Step 1/12 : FROM registry.website.com/base-image:latest
 ---> e2a0bcaf3dd7
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 27):

I think you're looking for [`docker-compose pull`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pull/):

```
$ docker-compose help pull
Pulls images for services defined in a Compose file, but does not start the containers.
```

So `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up` should do what you want, without needing to constantly wipe your cache or hard-code container names outside of your compose file

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? Does exactly what the question is asking. Thanks!

Comment: It does not do what the author asks for. It pulls the images for the services, but not base images specified in FROM in Dockerfiles

Answer (score 5):

This is the default behavior of `docker run` and similar commands: it will pull an image if you don't already have it, but if you do, it assumes the one you already have is correct.  In this case since the image isn't directly listed in the `docker-compose.yml` file you don't have a lot of shortcuts; you could script something like

```sh
sed -ne 's@^FROM \(.*/.*\)@\1@p' | xargs docker pull
```

to pull everything listed in a `FROM` line, but not base images for multi-stage builds (image names must contain a slash); that's possibly overkill.

I've seen several suggestions to avoid using `latest` tags; this is one of a couple of big reasons (you also don't control the major version of prepackaged software, and won't get consistent deployments on multi-host setups).  If you have a continuous-integration setup building your frequently-changing image, you might consider tagging it with a date stamp or build ID and putting that in the `FROM` line.  You can [use an `ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) to make this more configurable, and [pass that through from `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args), ultimately coming back to an environment variable.

I'd guess you'll probably wind up with a shell script wrapper no matter what, and if you're set on the `latest` version it could just look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
docker pull registry.website.com/base-image:latest
docker build -t ... .
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 3):

To re-pull your base images and re-build, run:

```
docker-compose build --pull
```

See [What's the purpose of "docker build --pull"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488535/whats-the-purpose-of-docker-build-pull) for more info.