# What's the purpose of "docker build --pull"?

Tags: docker

When building a docker image you normally use `docker build .`.

But I've found that you can specify `--pull`, so the whole command would look like `docker build --pull .`

I'm not sure about the purpose of `--pull`. Docker's [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) says "Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image", and I'm not sure what this means in this context.

You use `docker build` to build a new image, and eventually publish it somewhere to a container registry. Why would you want to pull something that doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

it will pull the latest version of any base image(s) instead of reusing whatever you already have tagged locally

take for instance an image based on a moving tag (such as `ubuntu:bionic`). upstream makes changes and rebuilds this periodically but you might have a months old image locally. docker will happily build against the old base.  `--pull` will pull as a side effect so you build against the latest base image

it's ~usually a best practice to use it to get upstream security fixes as soon as possible (instead of using stale, potentially vulnerable images). though you have to trade off breaking changes (and if you use immutable tags then it doesn't make a difference)

Comment: This is a very good explanation with the `ubuntu:bionic` image, since it (obviously) doesnt have a version attached, but will still be different whenever they publish a new image. All makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If the base-image would be `ubuntu:0.1.0` for example, and they published a new image but with the _same_ version i.e.  `ubuntu:0.1.0` - does this mean `docker build --pull` will re-download the entire new image again? (which would be what most people preferred I guess)

Comment: I am hoping someone will clarify the last question from @JimAho because that's what I want to understand better also. If the image had just been pushed, and nothing else changed, then is it the case that it is not rebuilt?

Comment: @learning2learn the answer is yes, the tag of a docker image is just a string so "0.1.0" is no different than the example in the answer "bionic"

Comment: If you want to be sure about the version of the image you are pulling, dont pull tags. Pull digests. You use the SHA hash signature of the image to be sure you get the image you expect. If you're on your dev machine using :develop tag, then --pull helps you stay current, but for production/helm charts, I switch to digests as its more reliable.

Comment: What about multistage builds with different base image for each stage?  Does `--pull` use the latest base image for each stage?

Comment: @Pino it takes you less time to just try it than to comment

Comment: @anthonysottile if someome that has already tried (you?) puts the answer here, it will save that time for all the others.

Comment: @Pino be the change you want to see then

Answer (score 12):

Docker allows passing the `--pull` flag to `docker build`, e.g. `docker build . --pull -t myimage`. This is the recommended way to ensure that the build always uses the latest container image despite the version available locally. However one additional point worth mentioning:

To ensure that your build is completely rebuilt, including checking the base image for updates, use the following options when building:

`--no-cache` - This will force rebuilding of layers already available.

The full command will therefore look like this:

`docker build . --pull --no-cache --tag myimage:version`

The same options are available for `docker-compose`:

`docker-compose build --no-cache --pull`

Comment: In normal use you shouldn’t need `--no-cache`.  If the base image is updated (and `--pull` gets a new version) that automatically invalidates the cache; similarly if you `COPY` different code that will invalidate the cache.  The only thing this will usually affect is if you’re doing something like `apt-get install` of a network-hosted package, in which case `--no-cache` will cause it to check for a newer version even if the base image hasn’t updated.

Comment: I guess that, when using `--pull`, if the base image hasn't received any update, `--no-cache` can be used to ignore/invalidate local cache anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer. `docker build` is used to build from a local dockerfile. `docker pull` is used to pull from docker hub. If you use docker build without a docker file it throws an error.

When you specify `--pull` or `:latest` docker will try to download the newest version (if any)

Basically, if you add --pull, it will try to pull the newest version each time it is run.

Comment: If you have layered images - will it pull all of them _always_?

Comment: If you have layered images, some will be cached on the machine (older layers) and whatever new layers will be pulled.

Comment: I would add that `--pull` is a great way to ensure images you build get the latest updates. If your Dockerfile references `node:16-buster` you would need pull to ensure you get all patches(e.g. 16.16.0).